# iPhone 4S using 3G to download songs from iCloud after iOS 5.1 update

Tags: icloud, music, iphone, ios, cellular-data

I have a limited 3G plan on my iPhone 4S and I also have iTunes Match service.

In order to keep the phone from downloading songs from iCloud, while under 3G connection, I had set 'Settings>Store>Use Cellular Data' to OFF. This seemed to work just fine until I downloaded the iOS 5.1 update.

A couple of days ago I was surprised to find that while listening to shuffled music, I had ran out of credit because the Music App had been fetching songs from iCloud using 3G, even though the Setting was still OFF.

I've been forced to turn off my 3G every time I want to listen to music on the go, which is really annoying.

Is this a known bug? Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? Is there a fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off "Use Cellular Data" in the "Music" section in Settings. Then, when you go to play a song from iTunes Match when you're on 3G, it'll give you a message saying you need to be on Wi-Fi.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Is this something new to 5.1? I didn't have this problem while running 5.0.

Comment: @pmd Honestly I don't remember, and I don't have any 5.0 devices around to test. Would not be surprised if they changed it though, they did change the 3G download limit from 20MB to 50MB

Comment: I think it did. I don't remember seeing that option before. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!